# Maths and human behavior graph and formulas

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

Can maths and psychology be connected somehow? I mean can we describe emotions and behavior by some variable or some formula that gives us same results in same situations from different persons?

I attended a seminar in which sir said that this graph can be seen as with three points we can think of it as three people and $+$ sign will say they are connected (friend or other) and $-$ sign will say disconnected (enemy or something like that or don't know each other).

Now suppose one point is girl $g$ and other two points are boys $b_1, b_2$.
Then if $g$ and $b_1$ likes each other, it's a $+$.
Also, the $b_2$ likes $g$ but $g$ does not like $b_2$, it's a $-$.

So the sign between $b_1$ & $b_2$ will become automatically $-$ from $+$ (if those two boys were friends).

But it's just an example what he explained if there are any other examples anyone know that connects human behavior and thoughts with mathematics please share.

It is much better if somebody tell me if it is possible to go with both the subjects in future, that will be great.

Comment: Certainly, probability and statistics can be (and are) used to describe human behaviour.  Almost any psychology experiment will use statistical methods.  But "same results in same situations from different persons"?  People are generally not predictable enough for that: you won't even always get the same results in the same situations from the same person.

Comment: So there is no way to predict behavior ? Not even how much percentage... If someone tell you their past experiences

Comment: Mathematics can be used to *describe* human behaviour, just as it can be used to describe other things in real life. However, whether human behaviour can be *predicted* mathematically is a question for psychology, not mathematics.

Comment: Actually I think it is a mathematical question..I read somewhere that everything in real world can be describe mathematically ...I don't know where I read that. This ques is combination of my previous memories and curiosity. It is said by Ramanujan (an equation has no meaning for me unless it expresses a thought of GOD). +some person (currently alive) with IQ 92.

Comment: @Rahul: this is a co-disciplinary matter. A psychologist is not prepared to build and validate mathematical models.

Comment: And I can't tag psychology and mathematics at the same time..as I said is there exist something at this point of time relating these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, aspects of human behavior can certainly be modelled mathematically, at least in a statistical sense (telling an "average" behavior around which there are fluctuations).

This requires to objectivate these aspects and measure then in a repeatable way. For instance, how can we rate "being in a good mood" ? An approach could be to count the number of smiles during an hour (assuming we can objectivate smiles sufficiently accurately ;-) ). (Now what is "$a$ likes $b$" ?)

But this is very far from the empirical and pretty naive "relationship arithmetic" that you describe. Human relations are much more subtle.

Comment: Do these kind of study have any special or specific name? In case someone wants to do anything in that direction?

Comment: @Ikuyuki: probably psychometrics (but this might have a restrictive meaning of cognitive testing).